# FetchRequest that uses a NavigationLink in a List

Tags: swiftui, binding, nsfetchrequest

is it possible to do something like that in SwiftUI to use a FetchRequest that uses a NavigationLink in a List:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Recipe.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Recipe>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: $item)) {
                        Text(item.wrappedName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: MyObject
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, Recipe!")
    }
}
```

Currently im getting the error:

```
Cannot find '$item' in scope
```

Comment: Since `MyObject` is a class anyway, you can simply remove `@Binding`. Then you can just pass `item` directly, no need for a binding.

Comment: You are right, Its a class and not a struct. I forgot about that. Post this as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: All coredata objects are observable objects. Why bind them vs just observe them? Change '@Binding' to '@ObservedObject' so you can edit it and see changes made in other Views.